# Typescript equivalent of python isinstance

Tags: python, typescript

What is the typescript equivalent of python isinstance

```
step1Choices: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
```

In python i can check `isinstance(step1Choices, list)`
How can i do the same in typescript ?

When i do `console.log(typeof step1Choices)` I get `object`

What i am looking for is to find out whether it is a list of strings or a dictionary(dictionary in python. Even though it is initialised as list, later i change it to dict)

Comment: But you already know that `step1Choices` is a `string[]`?

Comment: At a later stage i change it to another type.

Comment: You can just use `instanceof`.